# How to support a enum parameter with wildcard

Tags: powershell

I would like to declare a parameter in a PowerShell function that lets me do the following things:

1. limit the possible values to a limited set
2. allow multiple values (but no duplicates), like flags
3. support tab completion for possible values
4. allow the use of wildcards

For the first 3 requirements, I can use a simple `[ValidateSet('this', 'that', 'another')]` parameter that allows me to do this:

```
My-Command -MyParameter this, that
```

For example, say i have the following function:

```
function Resolve-ProtocolToDefaultPort {
    [Cmdletbinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ByProtocol', Mandatory)]
        [ValidateSet('FTP', 'FTPS', 'SFTP', 'HTTP', 'HTTPS')] 
        [string[]] $Protocol
    )

    foreach ($curProtocol in $Protocol) {
        switch($curProtocol) {
            { 'HTTP'  -like $_ } { return 80  }
            { 'HTTPS' -like $_ } { return 443 }
            # ...
        }
    }
}
```

How can i support this use case:

```
PS > Resolve-ProtocolToDefaultPort -Protocol HTT*
80
443
```

While retaining tab-completion and parameter validation?

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45553686/7890164) for wildcards parameters.

Comment: @Manu I didn't know about this attribute. Unfortunately, it doesn't do what is expected here..  `Resolve-ProtocolToDefaultPort : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Protocol'. The argument "HTT*" does not belong to the set "FTP,SFTP,FTPS,HTTP,HTTPS" specified by the ValidateSet attribute. Supply an argument that is in the set and then try the command again.`